# IdentityServer4 with multiple clients

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

I have multiple front facing web apps as well as an IdentityServer4 (micro-service) app, all running on .net Core MVC.  A given user may have multiple accounts on each of App1 and App2.  Once a user logs in they then select which account they are accessing.  If the user logs in on App1 and selects their account, they should also be able to log in to App2 and select an account without losing their identity on App1.  When returning to App1 their previously selected identity should still persist (no re-login required).  Additionally, if a user goes through the entire login process on App1, if they hit App2 w/o an App2 identity, they should not have to enter their initial credentials, just go straight to account selection.

The issue I'm having is that once I try to log the user in on App2, they completely lose their App1 identity.

Things I've tried:

1. I set up separate scopes for the two sites and can manage which site gets which info, which is great, but it doesn't solve the overall issue.
2. I've attempted to set up separate AuthenticationSchemes for the sites but so far that has been unhelpful, often leading to a completely unhelpful "server_error" message (no stack trace, nothing in the logs).

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Identity server 4 is Single sign on. Once user is logged in App1 if they hit App2 from App1 they don't have to login again. But each client have to authenticate itself. So you will be authenticating it, which the middleware will do automagically(you have to configure the client tho) and also make sure you dont share cookies between different clients.